# Insert to MySQL using HTML form

Tags: php, mysql, html

I would like to use the data entered in the html form and insert into MYSQL. I have a separate php (cus.php). but nothing is happening with current code I have

at the moment when I click "register" I'm nav to the php file. Thank you

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem: you really should escape your input values through `mysql_real_escape_string` or, even better, use PDO.

Comment: Not sure if this will break your code, don't have time to double check it all... but currently you have $conn = mysql_connect('???????', $user, $pass);  Why not put $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', $user, $pass);

Comment: @Zanrok Not all web hosts use `localhost` for databases. GoDaddy is a notable one, and if @Badr is using something like that, he wouldn't want his database server's IP/hostname on the web. I think ????? is just a placeholder.

Comment: @ceejayoz, thanks, ya I just thought it was odd seeing that in his code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, see DCoder's comment. It's the most important.

Change:

```
<form action="" method="seller">
```

To:

```
<form action="cus.php" method="post">
```

Does that fix it?

Comment: sorts the issue to an extent, I now get "This web page has not been found" when I click register.

Comment: Great! Now where is your cus.php in relation to this file? In the same directory, above or below? It seems they're in separate locations which is what is causing that error.

Comment: They are all placed in the same folder "demo" :( edit: edited it when I press reg it opens .php.

Comment: Very odd. And it's exactly "cus.php" not "CUS.php" or anything like that? Be sure to check everything in terms of file extension. When you get the "not found" message, if you look at the URL in the address bar, does it look correct?

Comment: What's the URL? It sounds like a server problem unless you forgot to open your PHP tag at the beginning.

Comment: file:///C:/Users/MO/Desktop/demo/cus.php, I have opened the PHP tag,I most of missed to paste in post but I do have it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9927/discussion-between-tcole-and-badr)

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the most important thing about an HTML form: the `<form>` tag.

You have to wrap the whole form (all inputs) which should be submitted when clicking like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="cus.php">
...
</form>
```

This will send all inputs to `cus.php` and make them available there as variables `$_POST['input_name']`. You can alternatively use GET as the method (and then use the $_GET array instead).

Edit: Didn't see it, you actually do have a form tag. However it's missing the target file in its `action` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
FORM action="your script" method="Post"
```